# MySQL server not fully utilized; threads_running is lesser than 2

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance, sqlperformance

I am running MySql 5.6 and I noticed that the CPU utilization never crosses 50% on an m1.large aws instance, when I benchmark the server (a few hundred queries executed in parallel over a period of time).

I have set the thread_cache variable to 50 and max_connections 500. When I execute the following commands from shell,

1. mysqladmin -u root -ppassword -r -i 1 ext | grep Threads_created

   I notice that Threads created never crosses 3
2. mysqladmin -u root -ppassword -r -i 1 ext | grep Threads_running

   I notice that Threads running never crosses 3, sometimes becomes -1.
3. SHOW STATUS; (Ran this from MySql Console)

   I notice that Threads_Cached is 0 in spite of the thread_cache_size being 50.

I am running a front end server to connect to forward requests to mysql. I am using a connection pool of size 50. Shouldn't the threads_created change to 50 right here? Is my understanding of this right?

UPDATE:

I updated my front end server from undertow to Jetty. I am now using c3p0 to do the connection pooling. I have configured to have 50 connections open and now I am able to notice threads_running and threads_running go up to 50.

*However, my CPU utilization still does not go beyond 60% for my mysql process.*

Machine details: AWS m1.large instance, 2 cores(4 vCPUs), 7.5GB RAM
MySQL Version : 5.6
Engine: MyISAM
Rows: 85 millions
Query type: Read only
Query: SELECT a,b,c FROM table WHERE text = ? AND date >= ? AND date <= ?;
I have a composite index on text,date fields and when I run EXPLAIN on this query, I am able to see that the index is being used.

Thanks,
V

Comment: This is my first time posting and I would love to know where I went wrong, so that I correct myself, rather than getting just a negative vote.

Comment: If you are benchmarking, how did you run the parallel mysql threads or queries? Did you disable the query_cache ?
The max thread is the upper cap and need not be always running

Comment: Hi cjg, 

I was using JMeter... Now I have a custom program that spawns 'n' specified threads. Each thread running 'k' specified number of queries..

I have not disabled the query cache! Should I be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many cores?  How many connections are *actively* doing things when you see 50%?  I'll guess that you have 2 cores and you have one connection active.  Since MySQL does not use more than one core per connection, that's 50%.

The "Thread" values you mention are OK.  Details...

"Thread_cache" is a confusing concept.  Here's what's going on:  When a new client tries to connect, mysqld (the server) looks in its "thread cache" to see if there are any there.  If not, it will create a new Operating System 'process' for that connection.  This is a moderately time consuming task, hence the desire for the cache.

When a connection disconnects (and there is no "connection pooling"), the process is put into the thread cache.  But the thread cache is capped at `thread_cache_size`.  That value of this `VARIABLE` should be 0 for Windows, and typically 10 for unix.  But the value does not matter a lot.

`max_connections` controls how many clients can simultaneously be connected.  Usually they are busy doing other things, so `SHOW PROCESSLIST` says "Sleep".  `wait_timeout` will forcibly disconnect those who Sleep longer than that setting (if they have not already voluntarily disconnected).

The `STATUS` value `Threads_created` says how many new connections have happened since MySQL started.  `Threads_running` says how many are currently connected, but not 'Sleep'.  (-1 seems 'wrong'.)  `Threads_cached` = 0 could mean, for example, that 3 clients have connected and they are still connected, plus you never had more than 3 connected.

Since you have a "connection pool", connections will tend to never die.

You have not hit 50 because you don't have enough clients to need 50.

The connection pool and the Thread_cache are serving the same caching purpose, but in different ways.  It's OK to have both, but you don't gain much by having both.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanations Rick! 

I have a 2 core machine(4 vCPUS, AWS, Xen virtualized).  I changed the front end server from Undertow to Jetty and using c3p0 for connection pooling. I am able to see more threads_running now. Also when connected clients disconnect.. the threads_cached goes up! 

However, the CPU utilization still does not cross 60% for mysql process.

Comment: I/O and other issues are usually the bottleneck.  MySQL sometimes consumes lots of CPU when a table has a poor index.