# MySQL threads_running stays at 3 at all time

Tags: mysql

32 Core Processor (Windows 2012), high power machine.  MySQL config has no restriction on number of threads.  But `threads_running` never exceeds `3` even when I can see lots of user activities on the front end and MYSQL monitoring shows over 1000 queries being executed per second.  Is it because queries are fast and more threads never needed to run concurrently?

```
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Slow_launch_threads 0
Threads_cached  0
Threads_connected   21
Threads_created 138
Threads_running 3
```

What changes in the config file to make, to make full use of server capacity?

These are config settings relating to threads.

```
thread_cache_size=10
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_purge_threads = 8
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587322/mysql-server-not-fully-utilized-threads-running-is-lesser-than-2

Comment: @DitgitalChris yes I saw that before I wrote this question but that answer didn't help.

Comment: What about Step 0- Check if you have a performance problem to Troubleshoot? http://www.speedemy.com/troubleshooting-mysql-performance-step-zero-check-performance-problem-troubleshoot/

Answer (score 0):

thread_cache_size = 100  # from 10 will reduce thread creation/destruction thrashing.   V8 indicates you should cap this number at 100 to avoid overload and possible oom.

For more detailed analysis, please add to OriginalPost the following:

```
RAM on the dedicated server
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

for up to five specific configuration recommendations to be applied one a day.